# Can't change global PATH environment in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04, path

I tried editing `/etc/environment`, changed it by removing `games` and adding my swift installation location, so now it looks like:
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/swift/usr/bin"`
That didn't work (even tried booting).
After searching for a solution, I came to realize that PAM aware applications (I have `UsePAM no` in my `sshd_config`, but I tried this anyway) use the file `/etc/login.defs`.
Went on and changed it, removed the `games` and added swift (to the `su` version as well).

```
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/swift/usr/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/swift/usr/bin
```

That didn't help as well.
After rebooting the machine - I still have `games` in my path, and no swift.
Tried removing `/etc/profile/apps-bin-path.sh`, my path is still:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Where is `games` coming from?
Why doesn't my path change?
I need this variable to be set for both login and non login shells, including non bash shells.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting, because I've just successfully removed `/usr/games` and `/usr/local/games` from the path by removing them from the `/etc/environment` file (and removing both directories by rm -r games). Ubuntu 18.04.